# What is DataImportHandler doing after Indexing completed?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr to index about 40m items, and the final index file is about 20G. Below is the message after a delta import:

```
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:51:44.149</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">5634016</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2012-09-27 01:25:17</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 5634016 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
```

I am wondering what solr is doing this status? and the message *replication?command=details* return is :

```
<lst name="masterDetails">
<str name="indexSize">36.69 GB</str>
```

The index is almost double, and is still going to be bigger. This made me very confused. I am doing delta import, why index will be double size when replace?

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing most of your documents that's normal. An update in lucene consists of a deletion and a re-insertion of the documents, since the index segments are write-once. When you delete a document, you are not really deleting it but only marking it as deleted, again because the segments are write-once.

Deleted documents will be deleted for real when the next merge happens, when a new bigger segments will be created out of the small segments that you have. That's when you should see a decreasement of the index size. That means that your index size shouldn't only increase. Merges happen more or less according to the merge policy in use. If you want to manually force a merge you can use the forceMerge operation, which is the new name for the optimize. Depending on the solr version in use you need to use either the first or the second one. Be careful, since the forceMerge takes a while if you have a lot of documents. Have a look at [this](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/simon-says%3a-optimize-is-bad-for-you) article too.

Comment: I have founded that my index only has one single segment, this may be the reason that cause the long time to delta import. I will try to set maxMergeDocs.

Comment: Nice, you might want to accept or upvote an answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Before Solr 3.6, dataImportHandler set optimize=true by default:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

This triggers merging of all segments into one regardless of other settings. I think you might be able to address this by adding an optimize checkbox to debug.jsp, though I haven't actually tried it.